# Is there a way to do NodeJs Express style Parameters in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

I am wondering if there is a way to have a Parameter in Angular route that is similar to NodeJs Style ?

i have a route which looks like this "**[http://myhost.domain.com/signin**"](http://myhost.domain.com/signin**%22) and i want to be able to pass an id for the signin request. I know i can do it like this "**[http://myhost.domain.com/signin?id=123456"](http://myhost.domain.com/signin?id=123456%22)**, but i am looking to do it more like a nodejs style where it would look like this **http://myhost.domain.com/signin/123456**

currently i read the params like this, but when i use the above url it cant find it since it thinks its one level deeper route.

```js
    ngOnInit() {
            this.route.queryParams
                .subscribe(params => {
            console.log(params); 
    
          }
        );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. First, you need to configure the route in the Router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'signin/:id', component: SignInComponent }
]
```

Then, you can access it in the component like this:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

...

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

...

ngOnInit() {
  const id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the id in this case optional ? i tried path: 'signin/:id?' which would be nodejs / express syntax but that does not work ? Or is the only solution to create another route without the /:id ?

Comment: Yes, if you have that use case, just add another route with same component: `{ path: 'signin', component: SignInComponent }`